# Python dominator radio and label

Tags: python, html, input

How do I add the html section below, in my document width dominator (python library).
Or rather where can I find examples.The [dominator](https://github.com/Knio/dominate) [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/dominator/) doesn't help me here.
I can create a string and add this in the document?

```
<input name="tabs" id="tab1" checked="checked" type="radio">
<label for="tab1">
```

Answer (score 0):

After 3 day's struggling I found the answer.

```
with div(cls='tabs',id='tab1',checked='checked', type='radio'): 
      with label(fr ="tab1"):
           span(cls="material-icons").add('Shield')
           text('your tekst')
```

Edit: Sorry for being unclear. Best guide for finding all the correct tags `https://github.com/Knio/dominate/blob/master/dominate/tags.py`
For the ones who want's to know. ;)

Comment: and: from dominate.util import text

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).